# How can I evaluate the instantaneous rate of change at $x = -7$ when given that $f '(x)= 3x-1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm not sure how to answer this question, I ended up getting the correct answer but I don't know why. I substituted $x$ for $-7$ within $f'$, but I don't think that's how you solve this problem. Would I have to use $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$? or is this another way to correctly solve this problem.

Comment: the derivative is given as $f'(x) = 3x-1$, so for $x=-7$ you indeed plug it in to get the correct answer.

Comment: $\lim_{h\to0}(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ would tell you how to compute the derivative from $f(x)$

Comment: Evaluate $f'(x)$ at $x=-7.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did **is** how you solve the problem.  The confusion is between

(i) computing the expression of $f'(x)$ (which you seem to have computed--that's where you use, at least in principle, $(f(x+h) - f(x))/h$), and

(ii) evaluating that expression at a specific point $x = a$ on the $x$-axis.

Notation that can help resolve this confusion is:
$$
\left.{df \over dx} \right|_{x = a}.
$$
It says, "first, compute the expression for $f'(x)$, and then evaluate that expression at $x = a$."  Your $a$ is $-7$.